# How to trigger animation when key pressed

Tags: javascript, css, animation, triggers, switch-statement

I have fully working the animation cycle when you click it, but how can I do the same switch effect when pressing A?. The same switch effect back and fort. Thank you so much.

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

**DEMO:**
https://jsfiddle.net/rihotzu/nywbvxqd/1/#

**HTML**

```
<!doctype <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>sprite test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="default"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.default{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(10361px / 11);
  height: 210px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/sz8vhOh.jpg);
  animation: open 0.5s steps(11);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.default2{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(10361px / 11);
  height: 210px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/sz8vhOh.jpg);
  animation: open 0.5s steps(11);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

.back{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: calc(10361px / 11);
    height: 210px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/sz8vhOh.jpg);
    animation: close 0.5s steps(11);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes open
{
    from
    {
        background-position: 0;
    }
    to
    {
        background-position: -10361px;
    }
}


@keyframes close
{
    from
    {
        background-position: -10361px;

    }
    to
    {
        background-position: 0;
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.default').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('default');
  $(this).addClass('default2');



  $('.default2').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('default2');
    $(this).addClass('back');



    $('.back').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('back');
        $(this).toggleClass('default2');
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your CSS and Javascript. I removed the nested click events and made a function for `click` and `keyup` event to avoid repetitive code. I also removed some class names and duplicates in your CSS.

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.default{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(10361px / 11);
  height: 210px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/sz8vhOh.jpg);
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(11);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.default.open {
  animation-name: open;
}

.default.close {
  animation-name: close;
}

@keyframes open
{
  from
  {
    background-position: 0;
  }
  to
  {
    background-position: -10361px;
  }
}


@keyframes close
{
  from
  {
    background-position: -10361px;
  }
  to
  {
    background-position: 0;
  }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function animate() {
  if($('.default').hasClass('open')) {
    $('.default').removeClass('open');
    $('.default').addClass('close');
  } else {
    $('.default').removeClass('close');
    $('.default').addClass('open');
  }
}

function animateOnKeyUp(e) {
    if(e.key === 'a') {
      animate();
    }
}

$('.default').click(animate);
$(window).keyup(animateOnKeyUp);
```

Comment: What I cant archive is to make it like a switch, like in my old example when you click it.  https://jsfiddle.net/rihotzu/nywbvxqd/3/

Comment: Your demo doesn't seem to have an issue.

Comment: yes, by clicking, but I would like to archive the same effect by just pressing A. :)

Comment: Add the code you have in your click event inside the `if` statement of my answer above.

Comment: If it worked and you find my answer helpful, an upvote would be appreciated.

Comment: your answer does not help at all

Comment: I made some changes in your code and made it cleaner. And I added the `keyup` event that triggers when you press A. Copy and paste the answer above in your code.

Comment: Absolutely great!, thanks! exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I see that you are using "a", what If I would like to use space? how do you call space now that you got rid of key codes?

Comment: Just a literal space: `if(e.key === ' ')`

Comment: Hi Jstarnate! can you help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128738/how-to-move-the-animated-key-on-top-of-the-keyboard-keeping-max-width100

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    toggleLeft=true;
    if (e.which == 65 && toggleLeft) { // 65 is For A
       $(this).removeClass('default');
       $(this).addClass('default2');
       toggleLeft=false
    }else if(e.which == 65 && !toggleLeft){
       $(this).removeClass('default2');
       $(this).addClass('default');
        toggleLeft=true
    }



};
```

Comment: Hi Tanveer, how can I make it switch? by pressing a, like when you click it: https://jsfiddle.net/rihotzu/nywbvxqd/3/

Comment: You mean when u press 'A' key on keyboard?

Comment: `event.which` is no longer recommended.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Comment: yes, lets say, when I press A, I would like to get the same effect that I already have when you click, it swap the classes and makes a switch, animation play, animation reverse, I did that calling default2 which plays and back which plays default2 in reverse.

Comment: run a onkeyup event like i showed. then identify the key which is pressed. if the key is a (e.which returns ascii code code for pressed key . for A its 65) then apply yopiur logic.

Comment: if you add this event on another key just change the ascii key code. you can see charcodes from https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html